# window floating above desktop but behind everything else

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I have my app all setup to do what i want it to do.
But there is one thing i can't figure out how to do. 
How do i make the window appear on the desktop.
As in its like on your desktop and it will be above the desktop, but behind everything else.

I haven't figured out how to do this...
Any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the key you are looking for is: kCGDesktopWindowLevelKey,
had a look for example and found
[Re: NSWindow order back and stay, dammit! -Applle mailing list](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2001/Sep/msg00051.html)

> "I think it would be better to do CGWindowLevelForKey(kCGDesktopWindowLevelKey)+1,
>   to make sure it's above the regular desktop, but below everything else.."

This Seems to work.

```
CGWindowLevel  desktopWinLevel =  CGWindowLevelForKey(kCGDesktopWindowLevelKey)+1;
[desktopWinLevel setLevel:winLevel];
```