# OSX App behind desktop

Tags: objective-c, macos, desktop, nswindow

There are some apps, that are being displayed between the desktop icons and the background, but how is this possible? What are the changes i need to make, to get my app displayed at this position?

Best regards

Comment: You have probably some thing set like what is talked about in this post.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775154/window-floating-above-desktop-but-behind-everything-else?rq=1

Comment: Hello, thank's for your comment. I guess that's exactly what i am searching for. :)